# SkiaSharp text drawn over canvas not saved

Tags: c#, image-processing, skiasharp

I'm drawing an SKBitmap on SKCanvas, then drawing some text over the canvas, then saving the image to disk. The text is not saved to the file on disk, and I only see the original bitmap. What am I missing ?

```
SKBitmap pngImage = SKBitmap.Decode(msBitmap.ToArray());
mycanvas.DrawBitmap(pngImage, 0, 0);
mycanvas.DrawText("Text", 10, 10, myBrush);
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(myfileName))
{ 
  SKData d = SKImage.FromBitmap(pngImage).Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
  d.SaveTo(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing both the bitmap and the text to the canvas (mycanvas) - but when you save, you are saving just the image data (pngImage). You need to get what is drawn on the canvas, and save that.

You might try the Snapshot() method, available on the surface (which owns the SKCanvas object).